# returning a "string" from a thread

Tags: c, string, casting, pthreads, return

I'm usying threads and I want that a thread reads a string and returns it to the main so I can use it in the main. Can you help me? This is what I do, but in the output it shows strange characters:

thread:

```
char *usr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
[...code...]
return (void*)usr;
```

main:

```
[...code...]
char usr[10];
pthread_join(login,(void*)&usr);
printf("%s",usr);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets alloc some memory in thread function and copy some string in that memory.

Then return the pointer of that memory from thread function.

In main function to receive the return value of that thread function use `pthread_join()` you need to type cast the receiver value as `(void**)`

see below code.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void *
incer(void *arg)
{
    long i;

        char * usr = malloc(25);
        strcpy(usr,"hello world\n");
        return usr;
}


int main(void)
{
    pthread_t  th1, th2;
    char * temp = NULL;

    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, incer, NULL);


    pthread_join(th1, (void**)&temp);
    printf("temp is %s",temp);

    if(temp != NULL)
      free(temp);    
  
    return 0;
}
```

This is what you want.

Comment: I strongly doubt that root cause for the OP's code failing, is the wrong cast of `pthread_join()`'s 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <exception>

std::string concatstring(const std::string& a,const std::string &b) {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "+" << std::endl;
    std::string c = a + b;
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "-" << std::endl;
    return c;
    }

int main() {
    try {
        std::future<std::string> fps = std::async(concatstring,"Hello","world");
        if (fps.valid()) {
            std::cout << fps.get() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " <<e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is only tagged as C related.

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that tag.